# Vis.js network ready function?

Tags: javascript, vis.js-network, vis.js

I am using Vis.js network to show graphs and was wondering if there's a specific `finishedLoading`event for the object?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the event afterDrawing, here is the [documentation](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/).

```
  myNetwork.on('afterDrawing', function(){ console.log('afterDrawing');});
```

Comment: Dead link. That's why you're supposed to provide full answers here, not a link to an answer.